# Examples of how the presence or absence 2'-hydroxyl groups influence physicochemical properties of DNA and RNA

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, nucleic-acids

I know, for instance, that RNA is much more succetible to alkaline hydrolysis than DNA and this difference is determined by the presence of 2'-hydroxyl group in ribose.
I have also heard that "DNA is more stable" and thus was selected as the repository of genetic information. Though, I still haven't understood why the lack of just one hydroxyl would lead to more stability...

Comment: @Chris ok, I will actually delete the other because something similar has already been asked

Comment: My answer to this question may interest you, specifically the part about sugar pucker: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19115/what-makes-dna-helical

Comment: From a chemical point of view, the phosphate can form a bond with the 2' hydroxyl, forming a cyclic structure and breaking the bond with the next nucleotide, thus breaking the RNA backbone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user137 said, the general base abstracts a proton from the 2'OH and subsequently the 2'O<sup>-</sup> renders a nucleophilic attack on the δ<sup>+</sup> Phosphorous, leading to the hydrolysis of the phosphodiester bond. There can be slight variations in the mechanism and the intermediates; for details see [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.199704321/pdf) review.

[image]

After hydrolysis both 2'- and 3'- phosphates can form.

RNA is not thermodynamically unstable; apart from being unstable in the presence of a strong base RNA is biochemically unstable too. This is because there are several RNAses and most of them degrade RNA by a mechanism similar to alkaline hydrolysis (they cannot act on DNA). Also see [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24786/why-deoxyribose-for-dna-and-ribose-for-rna/25792#25792) post.